# instagram timeline data model in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, schema, data-modeling, nosql

i want design timeline (Home) like instagram, but most sampled like ["twissandra-j"](https://github.com/eevans/twissandra-j/blob/master/persistence-cassandra/src/main/java/org/opennms/twissandra/persistence/cassandra/internal/CassandraTweetRepository.java)  used bellow schema:

```
     -- Users user is following
CREATE TABLE following (
    username text,
    followed text,
    PRIMARY KEY(username, followed)
);

-- Users who follow user
CREATE TABLE followers (
    username  text,
    following text,
    PRIMARY KEY(username, following)
);

-- Materialized view of tweets created by user
CREATE TABLE userline (
    tweetid  timeuuid,
    username text,
    body     text,
    PRIMARY KEY(username, tweetid)
);

-- Materialized view of tweets created by user, and users she follows
CREATE TABLE timeline (
    username  text,
    tweetid   timeuuid,
    posted_by text,
    body      text,
    PRIMARY KEY(username, tweetid)
);
```

**in this design**, every new post inserted, for each follower inserted a new record to timeline. if a user has 10k follower and 1000 users worked with application, program fails, Is there a better way?

```
// Insert the tweet into follower timelines
    for (String follower : getFollowers(username)) {
        execute("INSERT INTO timeline (username, tweetid, posted_by, body) VALUES ('%s', %s, '%s', '%s')",
                follower,
                id.toString(),
                username,
                body);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess, one of those 2 solutions/suggestions could help :

1)- 1st suggestion, insert into TIMELINE in a Batch mode of 1000 inserts statements for example.

```
execute("
  BEGIN BATCH
    INSERT INTO timeline (username, tweetid, posted_by, body) VALUES ('%s', %s, '%s', '%s')", follower, id.toString(), username, body);
    INSERT INTO timeline (username, tweetid, posted_by, body) VALUES ('%s', %s, '%s', '%s')", follower, id.toString(), username, body);
    INSERT INTO timeline (username, tweetid, posted_by, body) VALUES ('%s', %s, '%s', '%s')", follower, id.toString(), username, body);
    ...
    // n statements
APPLY BATCH");
```

- Batching multiple statements saves network exchanges between the client/server and server coordinator/replicas.
- One more thing, batches are atomic by default (in Cassandra 1.2 and later). In the context of a Cassandra batch operation, atomic means that if any of the batch succeeds, all of it will, otherwise none.

2)- 2nd suggestion, achieve insert into TIMELINE in an asynchronous mode (with success callback function in the front-end):

And of course, maybe you can combine both of them.

Comment: The exchanges (comments) with Eric Evans (Debian Developer, Apache Cassandra committer, and System Architect at The Rackspace Cloud) about this data modelling's issue in Twissandra: http://fr.slideshare.net/jericevans/cassandra-by-example-data-modelling-with-cql3.